# Unable to put values into HashMap<String, double>

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hashmap

Any ideas why I'm unable to `put` into this HashMap?

```
public class UserImpl implements User{
   HashMap<String, Double> videoRecords = new HashMap<>();

   @Override
   public void updateVideoRecord(String currentVideo, double seconds) {
       videoRecords.put(currentVideo, seconds);
   }
}
```

IntelliJ's debugger shows both `currentVideo` and `seconds` are passing value, but the HashMap `videoRecords` doesn't update. Here's what I used to detect the HashMap wasn't *accepting* the values:

```
@Override
public void updateVideoRecord(String currentVideo, double seconds) {  
    System.out.println(this.videoRecords);
    this.videoRecords.put(currentVideo, seconds);
    System.out.println(this.videoRecords);
}
```

The funny thing is that if I initialize a HashMap inside this method, the values are successfully put into it.

Comment: How do you know the values aren't being entered into the map? Can you show your runner code?

Comment: @ElanHamburger I posted an answer to your question. Thank you!

Comment: Add statement logging the value of the arguments (currentVideo and seconds), and post the output you get, and the output you expect instead. A complete minimal program that we could copy, paste and run would be nice.

Comment: Would you be able to post a minimal reproducible scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could add your runner code or at least your `main()` method, that would be of help. Anyways, I tried to to reproduce your problem but it seems to be working with no issues or whatsoever.

Here I used the same implementation of class `UserImpl` just like you, I just added a get method that returns the map to the `main` method:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class UserImpl implements User {
   HashMap<String, Double> videoRecords = new HashMap<>();

   @Override
   public void updateVideoRecord(String currentVideo, double seconds) {
       videoRecords.put(currentVideo, seconds);
   }

   public HashMap<String, Double> getRecords() {
       return videoRecords;
   }
}
```

Which implements from this 'Mock' interface, because in your implementation you're overriding the method `updateVideoRecord()`.

Obviously, in `Main` I create an object of the class `UserImpl`, puts a new entry to the HashMap and prints before and after the putting.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserImpl userImpl = new UserImpl(); 
        HashMap<String, Double> records = userImpl.getRecords();
        System.out.println("The size of the map is " + records.size());
        System.out.println("Initial Mappings are: " + records); 
        userImpl.updateVideoRecord("theCurrentVideo", 360);
        System.out.println("The size of the map is " + records.size());
        System.out.println("Initial Mappings are: " + records); 
   }
}
```

Lastly, here you can see the output looks completely as desired, so I don't see your problem. Therefore, if you could elaborate more your problem, maybe I can be of better help. If not, then I hope this has help you resolve your issue.

```
kareem@Kareems-MBP:Desktop$ javac Main.java
kareem@Kareems-MBP:Desktop$ java Main
The size of the map is 0
Initial Mappings are: {}
The size of the map is 1
Initial Mappings are: {theCurrentVideo=360.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your posts. I've been trying to debug this for hours and based on your responses there's no reason for that code not to work. You're right.

I'm trying to expand on someone else's existing code which is what was cause my code not to work. The HashMap `videoRecords` was being `Serialized` to a file, but in the process, a `toString()` method was erasing all records in side it.

It took me hours to figure this out...

@Kareem Jeiroudi: thanks for pointing me towards the right direction.